# Create a section at bottom of a Bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.force-to-bottom {
  background: grey;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: center; 
   height:200px;
}

#story {
 text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  padding:0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

html, body, .row, .container {
  height: 100%;
}


.container {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container fill-height">
  <div class="row">

    <div id="story" class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 style="text-align:center;">Demo</h1>

      <div class="row force-to-bottom text-center">
        <p>It's supposed to stay at the bottom of this section n goes across the whole screen</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a single page with multiple containers. I'm trying to create a section like a footer at the bottom of one of those containers. That footer should stay at the bottom of that section, but not at the bottom of the entire page. I've tried to add a `force-to-bottom` div but that did not work. How should I achieve this? Many thanks!

```
<div id="containerOne" class="container fill-height">
    <div class="row force-to-bottom text-center">
      <p>this is the footer of that one div</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="containerTwo" class="container fill-height">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flexbox to achieve this easily.

- Make the `#story` flex by giving it `display: flex` property along with `flex-direction: column` to align its children below each other vertically.
- Next to the `.force-to-bottom` children simply give the property `align-self: flex-end` to float to the bottom of its respective containers.

```css
html, body, .row, #story, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  background: pink;
}

.force-to-bottom {
  background: grey;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#story {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="payContainer" class="container fill-height">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="story" class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 style="text-align:center;">Demo</h1>
      <div class="row force-to-bottom text-center">
        <p>It's supposed to stay at the bottom of this section n goes across the whole screen</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update after OP updated code:**

Like I mentioned, for the above updated HTML structure you have. You need to apply `display: flex` to the `#story` div instead(not the `.container`). Also add another property `flex-direction: column` to make its children elements align below each other. `.force-to-bottom` styles remain the same.

Comment: Thanks! the code in your example works well, but for me, my container needs to be ` fill-height`, which is the height of browser. In this case that grey bar somehow goes across the middle of the div instead of stays at the bottom. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: It seems like some other properties or elements might be conflicting since your structure might be more complex. Could you create a codepen or Fiddle to replicate your issue along with `fill-height` and others, so we could debug the issue you are facing at your local.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question. Basically it's odd as if I take out the hight: 100px in your CSS, that container disappeared. I'm trying to have a container that fills the height of the browser, and a <div> at the bottom of that container

Comment: Yes ofcourse, since the container does not have any content except the footer, the rest of it disappears if you remove the height(one of the advantages of flexbox - dynamic in nature). Like I mentioned it would be better if you could replicate the issue you are facing in your local onto a Fiddle or so and give me the link to solve your issue.

Comment: Silly me. I've edited the question to show the issue. Thanks! This is how mine looks like now.

Comment: You can see that the grey bar somehow is not at the very bottom of that pink section, and it does not reach across to the right

Comment: @user4046073 - I have updated the answer. Check and let me know

Comment: Thanks! But the thing is, I want the container to be fill-height, which fills the entire browser. The current solution doesnt do that?

Comment: I mean if I add a line or remove a line, that will change the height of the container. Somehow that `container fill-height` does not take affect. I can see now the grey bar does stay at the bottom of that "story" div though.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that I'm trying to let that grey bar stays at the bottom of `fill height` container.

Comment: If you want fill-height, then you need to give all the container a `height: 100%` including `html, body, .row, .container`. I not sure but I think this is what you are after. Updated the answer. Check

Comment: You actually don't need the `fill-height` class to do that. Check the code snippet

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But you see that grey bar is still not as wide as the screen,.I tried to add width=100% to several places but that didnt solve the problem

Comment: That's because of `<div class="col-lg-1"></div>`. is that necessary ?

Comment: As of the heading <h1></h1>, that was moved down as the `story` div moved down, Do you reckon that I could just add some blank lines to move that up?

Comment: that `<div class="col-lg-1"></div>` helped to center things. I removed that and that grey bar moved to the left..

Comment: do you want "Demo" to be at the very top and footer to be at the very bottom ? Yes, remove that and increase the bootstrap class to 12 columns `<div id="story" class="col-lg-12">`. We can still center align that don't worry, we don't have to add the `col-lg-1` for that.

Comment: Also I figured the space is because of few bootstrap padding and margins being applied. To fix add `padding: 0;` to `#story` and `margin: 0;` to `.force-to-bottom`

Comment: Yes "Demo" at the top and footer at the bottom, that's exactly what I want to do. I removed `<div class="col-lg-1"></div> `, now should I add some blank lines? Also could you also enlighten me about how we center that content at the footer? I've updated the code in the question too.

Comment: No need for any blank lines. **To push demo at the top & footer at the bottom** - add `justify-content: space-between;` to `#story` and any desired height of say `height: 50px` to the `.force-to-bottom`. **To the content at the footer** just add `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` to `.force-to-bottom`. All these are updated in my answer's code snippet. Let me know if its all fine.

Comment: Note before checking the code snippets, it does not have bootstrap library. So alignment might not be as per your requirements, better check at your local as well.

Comment: Fantastic. Now the only problem is that after adding `height: 50px` to the `.force-to-bottom. `, it seems to have increased the height of that grey footer for me rather than create some space between Demo and the footer. I know it works fine in your code snippet. But any idea why it does that..?

Comment: I had a look in the inspector and that `  justify-content: space-between;` was applied, not overwritten

Comment: You need to apply `justify-content: space-between` to the `#story` not `.force-to-bottom`. Only the `height` goes to the `.force-to-bottom`. Can you also update the question to what your code looks like. Yes to avoid that increase in height you need to give `50px` to `.force-to-bottom` AND `justify-content: space-between` to the `#story`

Comment: Yes updated the question. My code looks pretty much the same as yours but I have no idea why the result doesn't look right. You can see in my result that grey area increased.

Comment: Yes, thats because you need to place the `html, body, .row, .container` CSS block above all the others. You need to make the `height: 100%` on the containers execute first. Hope this helps

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much buddy!

Comment: No problem .. Cheers